What is the number of people who match a certain criterion if $X$% do or know someone who does?
I saw an article on a newspaper that had the title "6 of every 10 people have experienced age based discrimination or know someone that have" and started wondering how many people have actually been suffering this because one person can know many more and that inflates the result.
My question is how can one calculate this and generalize the result assuming the condition is random? a social network is not exactly a random graph so I'm not sure if I even know how to simulate this situation.

You can at least bound it. In the "worst case", every $\frac{6}{10}$ people actually have experienced age-based discrimination. In the "best case", interestingly, you can just have $1$ person in the entire population $P$ who has experienced discrimination, and the remaining $\frac{6}{10} P - 1$ all know that one person. It's worth noting, of course, that neither of these extremes is likely to be the true situation.

A good estimation is $\frac{6}{10\cdot(k+1)}$ where a person knows $k$ people in average. It might change depending of the actual distribution, or on the actual social graph, but I don't think it will change by any sugnificant order of magnitude.

Can you please elaborate on how you came up with the estimation of $\frac{6}{10(k+1)}$?

If each person knows $k$ others then each person that experiences the discrimination accounts for $k+1$ of the people who have or know someone who has.  This presumes that nobody knows two people who have experienced it, a bad assumption when a large fraction of the population is involved.  It is even worse because you might have one company fire everybody over $50$ and they all know each other.

Since we don't have any good model as input I consider a Gilbert's random graph $G(n, p)$. It means that every pair of vertices are adjacent with probability $p$, and adjacencies of all pairs are mutually independent. And the question is: what is the expected number of labeled vertices if $s = nq$ vertices are labeled itself or adjacent to at least one labeled vertex?
Let's compute probability $f_{n, p}(\ell, s)$ that $\ell$ random vertices are labeled and $s$ vertices are labeled itself or adjacent to at least one labeled. For every single non-labeled vertex the probability of being adjacent to at least one labeled vertex is $1 - (1 - p)^\ell$. That's why
$$f_{n, p}(\ell, s) = \binom{n - \ell}{s - \ell}(1 - (1 - p)^\ell)^{s - \ell}(1 - p)^{\ell(n - s)}\\
= \binom{n - \ell}{n - s}(1 - (1 - p)^\ell)^{s - \ell}(1 - p)^{\ell(n - s)}.$$
Note that $\binom{n - \ell}{s - \ell} = \binom{n - \ell}{n - s} = 0$ for $\ell > s$.
So given numbers $n$, $p$ and $s$ the expected value of $\ell$ is
$$\frac{\sum_{x = 0}^{n} x \cdot f_{n, p}(x, s)}{\sum_{x = 0}^n f_{n, p}(x, s)} = \frac{\sum_{x = 0}^{s} x \cdot \binom{n - x}{n - s}(1 - (1 - p)^x)^{s - x}(1 - p)^{x(n - s)}}{\sum_{x = 0}^{s} \binom{n - x}{n - s}(1 - (1 - p)^x)^{s - x}(1 - p)^{x(n - s)}}.$$
I don't see an easy way to find a closed form (which may include a hypergeometric function) or an approximation. However it is already computable with good enough approximation of logarithm of factorial.
For example for $n = 1000$, $p = 0.(010)$ (i. e., average degree is $10$) and $q = 0.6$ we get $82.6677$ which is far from the "good estimation" of $54.(54)$ proposed by EnEm. For $n = 1\,000\,001$, $p = 0.001$ and $q = 0.6$ we get $914.918$ which is again far from naiive estimation of $599.4$. (The closer $q$ to $1$ the worse that estimation is, because it doesn't take into account two or more adjacent labeled vertices, which are more likely for bigger $q$.)
According to the Wall Street Journal "on average, people know $611$ others". So for $n = 333\,300\,000$ (approximate USA population), $q = 0.6$ and $p$ corresponding to expected vertex degree of $611$ we get $499018$.
